# Performance issue when executing the bash script by systemd

Tags: bash, fork, systemd, systemctl

I have the following issue.

I wrote a script in bash which have to make some operations on thousands of files. The main process forks about ten times to speed the whole execution up. The script works fine, as it is supposed to work.
The script have to be managed by the systemd.
I created the service file which have only:

```
[Unit]
Description=description

[Service]

ExecStart=script_path arguments

Type=simple
```

Unfortunately, the script started by the systemd is much slower than when explicitly running script.
What could be a root cause of this performance issue?
Does Type=simple fine for such case?
The script should be started sometimes and the main process should wait for the child processes to end.

Apart from that the script does not need any special treatment.

Comment: this could be primitive suggestion for debugging, you can put some echo statements in your script like  `echo stage1_$(date +%s) .. echo stageN_$(date +%s)`  in your script and redirect to some file in  `/tmp` fs. and you can see where its getting stuck for more time.

Comment: @PS. has a good idea. Find out is the slowness is during start-up, shutdown or some other time in the middle. systemd is not known to add much overhead so the issue could be somewhat specific to your cas.